# Is it possible to read the HTML body before the DOM-ready event?

Tags: javascript, html, loading, web-frontend, web-performance

I need to **read the HTML body content** (either as DOM or as a raw string) as soon as possible to optimize some loading of further scripts (load script A if content is X, or B if content is Y). Is it possible to avoid waiting for all `sync` scripts to load (which is a condition for DOM-ready) in order to read the body?

Note: changing scripts to be `async` is not an option.

Update: I do not control the server, so the optimization cannot be done there.

Comment: explore `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready);` where `ready` is a function to execute BUT the DOM may not all be loaded so `window.onload` is perhaps what you seek as the images will be loaded

Comment: Trying to read the body before it's loaded to manipulate what gets loaded sounds like a bad design. If you need different scripts to load based on content, that's really something for the server that's serving that content should do.

Comment: You can always access the DOM from inline scripts, but it won't contain nodes that are not parsed yet

Comment: "HTML body content" - what if they (scripts) are in the head?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps look at the state changes by subscribing to that.  Inline comments for each.

```js
// self envoking
(function() {
  console.log("self envoking in script");
}());
console.log(document.readyState); // logs "loading" first
window.onload = function() {
  console.log('onload'); // I fire later
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  console.log('DOMContentLoaded');
});
document.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {
  if (document.readyState == "loading") {
    //document is loading, does not fire here since no change from "loading" to "loading"
  }
  if (document.readyState == "interactive") {
    //document fully read. fires before DOMContentLoaded
  }
  if (document.readyState == "complete") {
    //document fully read and all resources (like images) loaded. fires after DOMContentLoaded
  }
  console.log(document.readyState)
});
```

```html
<script id="myscript">
  // self envoking
  (function() {
    console.log("self envoking with id");
    window.customevent = new Event('customload');

    // Listen for the event.
    document.addEventListener('customload', function(e) {
      console.log("customload fired");  
    }, false);
    // another way
    var scriptNode = document.createElement('script');
    scriptNode.innerHTML = 'console.log("happy happy day inject");';
    document.head.appendChild(scriptNode);
  }());
</script>
<script id="another">
  var thisScriptElement = document.getElementById("another");
  // self envoking
  (function() {
    console.log("Another self envoking with id");
    // Dispatch the event.
    document.dispatchEvent(customevent);
  }());
</script>
```

Comment: NOTE I do agree with others this is likely better done on the server before you get any of these.  Some ambiguity to the question here.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, although It didn't work for me: both `document.readyState == "interactive"` and `DOMContentLoaded` trigger after the `sync` scripts in the head download (at least on Chrome v68). About doing this on the server, I can't since I don't control that part (just updated the question with this detail).

Comment: @TomasRomero  I added some more options, not sure how/what you desire, put this FIRST on your page perhaps? -